# How to specify a format in CRM 2013 text field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I want to specify a specific format for a text field in `CRM 2013 Online` which will be in the following format `nnn-nn-nnnn`. After the first 3 digits are written a dash should appear or the dash should be there and only allow number in the above format.

Any help in `Javascript`?

Comment: do you want the value to be typed by user or it should be system generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks very similar to what you are trying to do:
http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2014/04/how-to-standardize-telephone-numbers-with-javascript-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/

I think the javascript solution is probably preferable to using a plugin.

Comment: Zach, this adds the hyphens later on `OnSave`function. I was hoping if the hyphens could be pre-loaded when the form is opened and the user could add the text between those hyphens like `xxx-xx-xxxx`

Comment: since i am using your solution now so I will mark this as answer. Thanks Zach

Answer (score 1):

If value is inserted by user then you can use something like following on `OnSave` event:

**Note: I have not tested this code. So please use this just to get an idea.**

```
function InsertHyphens() {
    var value = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_fieldname").getValue();
    value = value.replace("-","");
    if(!isNaN(value))
        {
            alert("Please only enter numeric characters only (Allowed input:0-9)")
            return false;
        }

    value = value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{3})/, "$1-$2-$3"); 
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_fieldname").setValue(value);
}
```

If value is system generated then you don't need above JavaScript, you can simply change the plugin which is generating the value.

Comment: no this does not work, plus i am looking for something that pre-loads the field with hyphens

Comment: If user is inserting the value, how can you pre load?

Comment: Unless you you are looking for something like Ajax Watermark.

Comment: the hyphens should be preloaded e.g, when the form is loaded the user should see the hyphens in the field and should be able to insert text in the following format xxx-xx-xxxx. Which means the user should be restricted to enter 3 digits before the first hyphen, 2 in the middle and four after. 
Solution proposed by @Zach takes a substring form the string entered and inserts the hyphens `OnSave` function. I was hoping if my above mentioned requirement could work